# Model cant find camera rotation

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

Im doing a project with AR.JS/Aframe. The project worked but recently all models that were displayed correctly are shown static on one place. IDK if this happend because of a libary update. Can someone tell me whats going on?

Imports:

```
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <script src='https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/master/dist/aframe-extras.loaders.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL = 'https://raw.githack.com/jeromeetienne/ar.js/master/three.js/'
    </script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/nicolocarpignoli/nicolocarpignoli.github.io/master/ar-playground/events.js"></script>
  </head>
```

Creating the model (This worked and hasnt been changed):

```
     let scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');
     let model = document.createElement('a-entity');

     model.setAttribute('position', '0 -1 -10');
     model.setAttribute('rotation', '10 0 0');
     model.setAttribute('gltf-model', `url(${data_url})`);
     scene.appendChild(model);
```

The a-scene:

```
  <a-scene
      sceneviewer
      vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
      embedded
      arjs='sourceType: webcam; sourceWidth:1280; sourceHeight:960; 
      displayWidth: 1280; displayHeight: 960; debugUIEnabled: false;'>
          <a-camera gps-camera rotation-reader></a-camera>
  </a-scene>
```

[image]

Comment: did you try using the newest versions of aframe and arjs?

Comment: yes I did, nothing changed from the current problem but thnx anyways

Comment: trying to [reproduce](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/shelled-local-shame?path=index.html%3A25%3A11), but i don't get any errors

Comment: do you get any errors with my glitch?

Comment: No i dont get any, its also not erroring in my project but just putting the object on a fixed place

Comment: btw I tried your glitch but the model is not getting the rotation reader from camera also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refresh the page after granting accesss to camera and mobile movement was the solution.